# toggle hiding main div on sub div

Tags: jquery

I have a main `<div>` `.main-drawer` and sub `<div>` `.main-hover-container` and on click the main `<div>` hides the sub `<div>` so far so good. Now the issue I am faced with is that the sub `<div>` has a URL link but on click it's triggering the toggle of the main `<div>`.

How can i exclude the `.main-hover-container` to not be effected on click so the link in the sub `<div>` can be clicked.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main-drawer").toggle(function(){
    $(this).closest(".main-drawer").find('.main-hover-container').stop(true).fadeTo( "fast", 1.0);
    }, function(){      
    $(".main-hover-container").fadeOut( "fast" );
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the source of event is child div then you can skip execution of funciton.

```
$(".main-drawer").toggle(function(event){
    if($(event.target).hasClass("main-hover-container"))
         return; 
    $(this).closest(".main-drawer").find('.main-hover-container').stop(true).fadeTo( "fast", 1.0);
    }, 
    function(){      
        if($(event.target).hasClass("main-hover-container"))
              return; 
        $(".main-hover-container").fadeOut( "fast" );
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. but its not working now ;( there seems to be an error in the return; when i use it in dreamweaver

Comment: Closing parenthesis of if was missing.